# Mount volume to docker to which sudo does not have access

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to mount a volume into docker on a compute cluster running ubuntu 18.04. This volume is on a mounted filesystem to which my user has access, but sudo does not. I do have sudo permissions on this cluster. I use this command:

```
docker run -it --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/logs,target=/workspace/logs tmp:latest bash
```

The result is this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": stat /home/logs: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Mounting the volume works fine on my local machine where both sudo and I have access to the drive I want to mount, which makes me believe that the problem is indeed that on the server sudo does not have permissions to the drive I want to mount into docker.

What I have tried:

- running the post-install steps `$ sudo groupadd docker && sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
- running docker with `sudo`
- running docker with `--privileged`
- running docker with `--user $(id -u):$(id -g)`
- setting the user inside the dockerfile with `USER $(id -u):$(id -g)` (plugging in the actual values)

Is there a way to mount the volume in this setup or to change the dockerfile to correctly access the drive with my personal user? Any help would be much appreciated.

On a sidenote, within docker I would only require readaccess to the volume in case that changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container is created by the Docker daemon, which runs as root. That's why it still doesn't work even if you run the container or the `docker` command as your own user.

You might be able to [run the daemon as your own user](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) (rootless mode).

You could also look at changing the mount options (on the host system) so that the `root` user on the host *does* have access. How to do this depends on the type of filesystem.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to give root access to that mount.
But thank you for the tip on the docker rootless, that seems to be the solution - in theory, as I am running into another issue with it (`failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: lchown /etc/gshadow: operation not permitted`). But marking your answer as correct as that is most likely a separat issue

Comment: I opened a new issue for my problem with docker rootless: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66012208/docker-rootless-unable-to-pull-images